# CodeIgniter reCaptcha and Form_validation class

Tags: codeigniter, validation, recaptcha

I have a simple contact form with several required fields which is working fine. I am trying to add reCaptcha to the form for some added spam protection.

I have the reCaptcha displaying on the form correctly, I have my keys installed. In my controller I can call the recaptcha_check_answer method and get back valid responses. I have all of the files installed and configured correctly as I can use the methods from the recaptcha class and get back good responses.

My issue is that I would like to have an invalid reCaptcha trigger a CI form_validation error but I have spent alot of time on this and cannot get it to trigger. I am pretty new to CI so pardon my ignorance if this is something easy.

I have tried to throw a form_validation error when the is_valid response comes back NULL. If NULL then I tried to do the following:

```
$this->form_validation->set_message('recaptcha_response_field', 'reCaptcha', lang('recaptcha_incorrect_response'));
echo form_error('recaptcha_response_field');
```

Here is what the reCaptcha API responses look like for Valid and Invalid captcha's:

```
Valid = stdClass Object ( [0] => is_valid [1] => error [is_valid] => 1 )
Invalid = stdClass Object ( [0] => is_valid [1] => error [is_valid] => [error] => incorrect-captcha-sol )
```

Here is the code I have in my Controller:

```
class Contact extends CI_Controller 
{

function __construct()
{
  parent::__construct();
}

public function index()
{
  $this->load->library('recaptcha');
  $this->recaptcha->set_key ('MY_PUBLIC_KEY_HERE' ,'public');
  $this->recaptcha->set_key ('MY_PRIVATE_KEY_HERE' ,'private'); // For private key

     // Is this a Form Submission?
     if (!empty($_POST))
     {

        // LOAD VALIDATION AND SET RULES
         $this->load->library('form_validation');
         $this->load->helper('form');


        $this->form_validation->set_rules('first_name', 'First Name', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('last_name', 'Last Name', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|valid_email');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('recaptcha_response_field', 'reCaptcha', 'required|recaptcha_check_answer');
        $this->_resp = $this->recaptcha->recaptcha_check_answer ( $this->input->ip_address(), $this->input->post('recaptcha_challenge_field',true), $this->input->post('recaptcha_response_field',true));

        // If the reCaptcha doesnt match throw an form_valiation Error
        if ($this->_resp->is_valid == '')
        {
            $this->form_validation->set_message('recaptcha_response_field', 'reCaptcha', lang('recaptcha_incorrect_response'));
            echo form_error('recaptcha_response_field');
        }



        if ($this->form_validation->run() !== FALSE)
        {
           // SUCCESS NO ERRORS - SEND EMAIL DATA AND RETURN TO HOME
              $this->load->library('email');   // LOAD EMAIL LIBRARY
              $config['protocol'] = 'sendmail';
              $config['mailpath'] = '/usr/sbin/sendmail';
              $config['charset'] = 'utf-8';
              $config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;

              $this->email->initialize($config);

              $this->email->from($this->input->post('email'), $this->input->post('first_name').' '.$this->input->post('last_name'));
              $this->email->to('jassen.michaels@gmail.com');
              $this->email->cc('');
              $this->email->bcc('');

              $this->email->subject('Contact Email From Spider Design Website');
              $this->email->message(
                    'First Name: '.$this->input->post('first_name')."\r\n".
                    'Last Name: '.$this->input->post('last_name')."\r\n".
                    'Company: '.$this->input->post('company')."\r\n".
                    'Location: '.$this->input->post('location')."\r\n"."\r\n".
                    'I am interested in learning: '."\r\n"."\r\n".
                    'Information Architecture: '.$this->input->post('information_architecture')."\r\n".
                    'Web Design: '.$this->input->post('web_design')."\r\n".
                    'Graphic Design: '.$this->input->post('graphic_design')."\r\n".
                    'Email Marketing: '.$this->input->post('email_marketing')."\r\n".
                    'Social Media: '.$this->input->post('social_media')."\r\n".
                    'Content Management: '.$this->input->post('content_management')."\r\n".
                    'Search Engine Optimization: '.$this->input->post('seo')."\r\n".
                    'Web Traffic Analytics: '.$this->input->post('wta')."\r\n"."\r\n".
                    'Preferred Method of Contact: '."\r\n".
                    'Phone: '.$this->input->post('phone')."\r\n".
                    'Email: '.$this->input->post('email')."\r\n"."\r\n".
                    'Comments: '."\r\n".
                    $this->input->post('comments')            
                    );

           //$this->email->send();
           //$this->load->helper('url');
           //redirect('http://sdi.myspiderdesign.com/fuel');
        } 
     }

         // Not a form submission, load view
         $this->load->helper('form');
         $this->load->view('include/spider_header');
         $this->load->view('contact');   // Content Area
         $this->load->view('include/spider_footer'); // Footer
   }
}
```

I have commented out the redirects and contact email at the bottom of the form until I can troubleshoot this issue.

Thanks in advance for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

I used the callback_ function within the form_validation library. Setup an additional function inside the controller that made the API call and if the captcha did not pass it would throw a validation_error.